# Are there commercial (ready-made) external hard disk cases for USB?

Tags: usb, external-hard-drive, case, enclosures

Are there commercial (ready-made) external hard disk cases for USB? I have unused IDE hard drives that I don't use anymore and I thought I could use as transfer media.

However I haven't found in online shops such items and I am afraid I might not be making the right queries and/or not using the right keywords.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, they are commonly called hard drive enclosures.  Here's some at Newegg:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=Property&Subcategory=92&Description=&Type=&N=2010010092&srchInDesc=&MinPrice=&MaxPrice=&PropertyCodeValue=538%3A7123&PropertyCodeValue=541%3A7130&PropertyCodeValue=542%3A13783&PropertyCodeValue=542%3A47649&PropertyCodeValue=542%3A7135&PropertyCodeValue=542%3A46122&PropertyCodeValue=542%3A7138&PropertyCodeValue=542%3A44018&PropertyCodeValue=542%3A7137&PropertyCodeValue=542%3A7132

Answer (score 1):

Try searching for External Enclosures.  Here's a link to a bunch from newegg.com:

http://www.newegg.com/Product/ProductList.aspx?Submit=ENE&N=2010010092+1054107130&QksAutoSuggestion=&ShowDeactivatedMark=False&Configurator=&Subcategory=92&description=&Ntk=&CFG=&SpeTabStoreType=&srchInDesc=

Comment: add IDE to your query to narrow down the results

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use an external drive enclosure to connect an IDE or SATA drive to a USB port.

NewEgg does not deliver to Romania, so here's a few alternatives to get you started:

- [Alibaba](http://www.alibaba.com/trade/search?SearchText=external+hard+drive+enclosure&Country=RO&CatId=0&IndexArea=product_en&ssk=y&sq=y)
- [Computer Center](http://www.computercenter.ro/products.php?category_id=83)
- [eBay](http://groups.ebay.com/forum/Romanian-Ebay-Official/Cover-Page/1600025302)
- [Computer Sales](http://www.computersales.ro/componente-pc--hard-disk--usb--interf.htm)

HTH